# How to secure tcp connection - nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, authentication, tcp

I have following `sample code` used in the `tcp server`

```
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function (socket) {

   if(restrictedIP == sock.remoteAddress){
      //How to close the particular connection safely without 
      //affecting other connections
   }

  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);        
  });

  socket.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

#### Note : I have a check to authenticate the client/server ip (3rd line).

#### Problem :

1. Whether this logic sounds good to authenticate the client/server.
2. Main thing, How to close the particular connection from the restricted ip address.(4th line - comment)

#### Scenario :

I have two servers one is client server which is express/http server lets name it as `server1-express`, and other one is tcp server named as `server2-tcp`.

1. `server1-express` server will talk to `server2-tcp` using tcp.
2. `server2-tcp` should only allow this particular `server1-express` server, It shouldn't allow connection to any other ip,
3. Using socket.destroy() will crash the `server2-tcp`.
4. Using socket.end() will force us to `write` to servers.

#### How to allow only particular `ip` and deny all other `ip` access?

Any help or suggestion will be grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "authenticate", but obviously an IP address could be used by multiple people (e.g. behind a router). So if that is a concern, you will have to come up with your own protocol or re-use an existing one (probably a better idea to use one that has been "battle tested"). A more "complex" example would be to use [TLS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html), which is built into node and would give you both encryption *and* authentication via certificates/keys, while still giving you a raw socket.

As far as terminating a connection goes, you can do that gracefully by calling `.end()` on the socket, or `.destroy()` to forcefully terminate the socket.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have two servers one is client server which is express/http server, and other one is tcp server. Express/http server will talk to tcp server. Tcp server should only allow this particular express/http server, It shouldn't allow connection to any other server from different ip, If i use socket.destroy() server got crashed.

Comment: Edited the question please check